# Passing variable as input in Oracle SQL using Python

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to pass a variable containing string values into a SQL query with in statement using python . the query gets executed successfully but the result comes as blank. any idea how to pass a variable containing string values into a SQL query with in statement using python

```
a=('Vndr1','Vndr2')
Import cx_oracle
{
Connection
SQL="""

Select ....
....
and hcp.code in :a"""

}
cur.execute(SQL,{'a',a}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From [the `cx_Oracle` documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause), pass the values in individually:

```py
a=('Vndr1','Vndr2')
cur.execute(
  """
  SELECT ...
  FROM   ...
  WHERE  ...
  AND    hcp.code in (:v1,:v2)
  """,
  v1=a[0],
  v2=a[1],
)
```

---

Or use a collection:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE name_array AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(25);
/
```

then:

```py
type_obj = connection.gettype("NAME_ARRAY")
obj = type_obj.newobject()
obj.extend(["Vndr1", "Vndr2"])
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT ...
    FROM   ...
    WHERE  ...
    AND    hcp.code MEMBER OF :1
    -- or
    -- AND    hcp.code IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(:1))
    """,
    [obj],
)
```

Comment: The collection should only be used for _very_ large numbers of values, since this solution takes a few round-trips and is relatively slow.  Using a fixed number of bind placeholders is going to be better for most cases.  The linked doc discusses this all.

Comment: Hi , number of values in variable are not fixed  as I am fetching it from.another query
I tried using the l
Range option from the query but it didn't work.